# Tf timeout with multiple machines

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, machines, stack, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I try to get the navigation stack running on my robot.
I've got ROS running on the robot and on an PC used for visualization in Rviz and, if possible, for calculation like gmapping.

Nodes i need:
odometry_publisher; base_control; tf_broadcaster; rviz; gmapping; depth_to laserscan; freenect(kinect); move_base.

I tried to distribute the nodes on the two PC in so may different combinations. But i allways get the same problem:

When i start all the nodes on my robot like: Odometry_publisher, freenect(kinect) and base_control everything looks good.
Then i start the rest of the nodes on the other PC.

In rviz it needs one minute until the laser scan in shown( before it tells that there is no transform from base_link to map). even if the laser scan is not visible in rviz, gmapping is building  map
After that minute all of my nodes work fine. the is tha map made by gmapping and all the sensordata is published.

BUT:
Starting the Navigation stack produces that Warning and does nothing afterwards:

```
 [ WARN] [1532685774.079683838]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1532685692.802003361 but the earliest data is at time 1532685767.757000016, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]. Transform returned after 0.100864 timeout was 0.1.
```

btw  i does make no change where the master runs
I think my time is completely messed up.
anyone an idea how to fix that?

thanks you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298821/tf-timeout-with-multiple-machines/) by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
First thing to check: are the clocks between all involved machines in-sync? If they are not, you'll run into the issues you describe.

See #q11570.

**Comment by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on 2018-07-27**:
thanks for the hint!
I try that:

```
 ros@ros-ThinkPad-T410:~$ ntpdate -q ros-robot
```

and got:

```
server 10.42.0.1, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
27 Jul 13:35:32 ntpdate[1719]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

so i think the machines are in sync, right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:\

> so i think the machines are in sync, right?

No, I don't think so:

> ntpdate[1719]: no server suitable for synchronization found

I would say this means that synchronisation failed.

Please check the question I linked and their use of `chrony`.

**Comment by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on 2018-07-27**:
ok, do you have a simple tutorial how to setup chrony. Im a bit lost :)
thanks!!

**Comment by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on 2018-07-27**:
what i did so far:

```
apt-get install chrony
```

add this line to  /etc/chrony/chrony.conf:
server ros-robot minpoll 0 maxpoll 5 maxdelay
.1

restart Pc

```
sudo /etc/init.d/chrony stop
sudo /etc/init.d/chrony start
```

i properly did something wrong =)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
Perhaps [How to use chrony to synchronize timestamp on two computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787855) helps.

**Comment by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on 2018-07-27**:
thank you, i've got chrony runnning but still 0.308 s offset between the machines.
so now the Warning is:

```
[ WARN] [1532696225.143471688]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1532696225.1434, global_pose stamp: 1532696224.7965, tolerance: 0.3000
```

so I'm realy close to  a working time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!
I got this working!
As gvdhoorn sad, the machines where not in sync!
To solve this:

try `ntpdate -q <IP of your time server>`

if you get  `no server suitable for synchronization found`

do on both machines:     `apt-get install chrony`

choos one machine as time server. do on this machine: `sudo nano /etc/chrony/chrony.conf`

Add these lines:

```
# make it serve time even if it is not synced (as it can't reach out)
local stratum 8
# allow the IP of your peer to connect
allow <IP of your time-clinet>
```

Then do on the time clinet(machine that changes its time towards the server): `sudo nano /etc/chrony/chrony.conf`

Add these lines:

```
server <server_ip> minpoll 0 maxpoll 5 maxdelay .05
```

change maxdelay as you wish. 0.05 worked for me!

restart both machines

check with `ntpdate -q <IP of your time server>`

if they still have a big offset do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/chrony start
sudo /etc/init.d/chrony stop
```

check again. The offset should now get better.

hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) with karma: 123 on 2018-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2021-11-12**:
In my case, I changed to 0.0005.

The out put:   `ntpdate -q 192.168.xx`

server `192.168.xx`, stratum 3, offset 0.000688, delay 0.03365
12 Nov 14:54:28 ntpdate[5375]: adjust time server `192.168.xx` offset 0.000688 sec.

Really, It is not familiar to me.

It is fine or not?

please, let me know if I will get any problems.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2021-11-12**:
I also got this:

```
server 192.168.xx, stratum 3, offset -0.012946, delay 0.04585
12 Nov 15:09:38 ntpdate[6213]: adjust time server 192.168.xx offset -0.012946 sec
```